# A question on Multiple RegionPlots

Tags: plotting

I want to find the output of RegionPlot for a simple condition namely n*(x + y) < 1, where n is a varying number.

Here I have used Manipulate command in order to generate multiple RegionPlots (with different areas) for varying n values.

Manipulate[RegionPlot[{n*x + n*y < 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {n, 1, 10, 0.1}]

Now I want to generate a single region whose area changes with n for all values n=1..10, and also its color (or color intensity) varies as n changes.

So for example, as n decreases the intensity of the color decreases and this intensity is shown as a Legend near the diagram.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{n*x + n*y < 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {1, 10}]]], {{n, 5}, 1,
   10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Legended[
 Show[
  RegionPlot[
     {#*x + #*y < 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
     PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {1, 10}]],
     PlotPoints -> 75,
     MaxRecursion -> 5] & /@ Range[10]],
 SwatchLegend[
  ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {1, 10}]] & /@ Range[10], 
  Range[10]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bob, is it possible to make the jumps between colors continues so that the change in color occurs more smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

To get the continues effect I think we need to use `ColorFunction`,here we try the `LinearGradientFilling` .

```
normal = {1, 1};
Manipulate[
 Region[Style[ImplicitRegion[n*normal . {x, y} < 1, {x, y}], 
   LinearGradientFilling[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[0, 1, .1], 
    ArcTan @@ normal]], PlotRange -> All], {n, 1, 10, .1}]
```